# Unlink a symbolic link user selected in NSOpenPanel via PowerBox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox, nsopenpanel

In Cocoa, namely on OS X, I'd like to unlink a symbolic link that user selected in `NSOpenPanel` under the Sandboxed environment.

The code I'm writing is the following:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
openPanel.resolvesAliases = NO;
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = NO;
openPanel.allowedFileTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeSymLink];

[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[[self view] window]
                  completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode)
 {
     if (returnCode == NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton) { return; }

     int status = unlink(openPanel.URL.fileSystemRepresentation);

     if (status < 0) {
         NSLog(@" failed unlinking symbolic link at %s", openPanel.URL.fileSystemRepresentation);
     }
 }];
```

Setting `NO` to `resolvesAliases` property works well so as not to resolve symbolic link. Thus, `openPanel.URL` returns the correct location that user selected in the openPanel.

However, `unlink` command fails with status `-1` since PowerBox doesn't give the write permission for the symbolic file at the URL that user selected.

I of course added `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` key with `YES` to my entitlements file. In addition to that, I'm using Xcode 6.4 + OS X 10.10 SDK, and running this on OS X 10.10.5.

How can I successfully unlink a symbolic link that I let user select?
Or, is it impossible to unlink a symbolic link under the Sandboxed environment at all?

[Note] I can't substitute symbolic link with either OS X's alias or UNIX's hard link on this situation. It must be a symbolic link.